# Maven plugin: I am haven this error when i try to run mvn dependentcy: tree in cmd

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, portlet, maven-assembly-plugin

No plugin found for prefix 'dependentcy' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories

I tried to see the dependency tree     mvn dependentcy:tree

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there's a typo in your command. Instead of "mvn dependentcy:tree", it should be "mvn dependency:tree"

Comment: Sorry, I used mvn dependentcy:tree and I am having the same problem

Comment: could you help?

Comment: You mean even with "dependancy:tree" with no t between the n and the c does not work ?

Comment: I keep getting this error:  No plugin found for prefix 'dependentcy' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories